# How to increase textares's limit?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm developing using Blazor server-side.

When I copied and pasted a lot of words to textarea, the error **Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'** was occurred.

```
<textarea rows="3"
          id="textArea1"
          @bind-value="data"
          @bind-value:event="oninput" 
          />
```

The error had occurred when I copied and pasted about 90kb data. But small datas are working well.

So I wanna ask to you how to increase textarea's limit? or what is the best way to control huge datas.

Please help me.

Comment: Maybe it's because you limit the rows? Try taking that out or increasing the `maxlength` attribute

Comment: @Sean I removed `rows` and added `maxlength` however both were not worked.

Comment: `When I copied and pasted a lot of words to textarea, the error **Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'** was occurred.` A Blazor Server app is built on top of ASP.NET Core SignalR. As @SuprabhatBiswal mentioned, you can try to increase the value of [`MaximumReceiveMessageSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices` add a option to `AddSignalR` service. By default the incoming hub message size is 32KB.

```
services.AddSignalR(options => { options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null; });
```

Setting `MaximumReceiveMessageSize` to `null` means no limit. You can even set a value to it in bytes if you wish to limit the size of message transfer. Please check [ASP.NET Core SignalR configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options) for more detail.